# What happens to the substance of a Eucharistic host after it is consumed?

Tags: transubstantiation

Ofter eating an object that appears to us to be a wafer, but is really fully Jesus, our body digests the accidental bread like part of the object.  However, what happens to the substantial part?  Does it become separated from the accidental bready parts, so the bready parts become substantially bread again?  And if the substance is separated, what happens to the substance?  The substance is Jesus, and I think Jesus 'unifies' with us and makes us 'whole'.  What does that mean exactly?

Also, does the 'unifying' and 'wholeness' only happen if we take the Eucharist if we are correctly disposed?  If so, what happens to the substance when we are in mortal sin?  Does the substance leave us?  Does a reverse transubstiation occur, and the object's substance gets turned back into a wafer?

Comment: duplicate?: "[According to Catholics (and Mark 7:19) what happens to Jesus' flesh after it is ingested?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/66898/1787)"

Comment: Yes, it answers most of the question.  I can ask the unanswered part separately.  Thanks!